# plugin_not_installed in this.googlePlus.login() function

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3, ionic-view

I'm trying to use Ionic [google plus plugin](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/google-plus/) in my Ionic application.
I have a error `plugin_not_installed` in Android device when I call this.googlePlus.login() function:

```
this.platform.ready(() => {
    this.googlePlus.login({})
        .then(res => console.log(res))
        .catch(err => console.log(err));
});
```

I installed plugin using commands:

```
ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-googleplus --variable REVERSED_CLIENT_ID=myreversedclientid
npm install --save @ionic-native/google-plus
```

And I added `GooglePlus` to my providers list in `AppModule`

I upload application using command: `ionic upload`

Here is my plugins list (ionic cordova plugin):

```
cordova-plugin-camera 2.4.1 "Camera"
cordova-plugin-compat 1.1.0 "Compat"
cordova-plugin-console 1.0.7 "Console"
cordova-plugin-device 1.1.6 "Device"
cordova-plugin-googleplus 5.1.1 "Google SignIn"
cordova-plugin-inappbrowser 1.7.1 "InAppBrowser"
cordova-plugin-nativestorage 2.2.2 "NativeStorage"
cordova-plugin-statusbar 2.2.3 "StatusBar"
cordova-plugin-whitelist 1.3.2 "Whitelist"
cordova-sqlite-storage 2.0.4 "Cordova sqlite storage plugin"
ionic-plugin-keyboard 2.2.1 "Keyboard"
phonegap-plugin-push 2.0.0-rc5 "PushPlugin"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like the `cordova-plugin-googleplus` is not yet supported by `Ionic View`. You can find a list of the supported plugins **[here](https://docs.ionic.io/tools/view/#supported-plugins)**.

As of today (July 31, 2017), the list of supported plugins is:

```
View supports a subset of the plugins found in Ionic Native:

ActionSheet 2.2.2
BarcodeScanner 5.0.0
BLE 1.1.1
Bluetooth Serial 0.4.5
Calendar 4.5.0
Camera 2.2.0
Capture 1.3.0
Contacts 2.1.0
DatePicker 0.9.3
DBMeter 1.0.3
Device 1.1.2
Device Motion 1.2.1
Device Orientation 1.0.3
Dialogs 1.2.1
Email Composer 0.8.3
Geolocation 2.2.0
Globalization 1.0.3
ImagePicker 1.1.1
Keyboard 2.2.0
Media 2.3.0
Network Information 1.2.1
SocialSharing 5.1.1
SQLite 1.4.2
StatusBar 2.1.3
Toast 2.5.2
Touch ID 3.2.0
Vibration 2.1.1
```